# Sitecore experience Editor Pop up One or more items have been changed. Do you want to overwrite these changes?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

In Experience Editor Whenever we try to save the item for first time it works correctly.

but as soon as we try to save same item second and further time we get a popup message saying that

"One or more items have been changed. Do you want to overwrite these changes?"

which was not in sitecore 7 ??

So please let me know this is the functionality or it is some kind of BUG

Comment: This definitely looks like a bug. Raise this with Sitecore Support.

Comment: I've noticed this issue before when Edit Frames are used with custom buttons to programatically create items in the background. I would check on a clean install of Sitecore first before raising it as a bug.

Comment: Do you have by any chance multiple editors working on the same item (one you were editing?)

Comment: Did you get any resolution to this issue?  It is happening to us also.